# File Seek in a dynamically increasing file

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, io, filechannel

I am trying to save a online stream locally and then distribute the stream from my local node.

Program flow:

First request for a url, url-test, creates a single writer thread which starts writing to the file system with file name, url-file. All subsequent requests for that url, url-test, are handled from the local file system.

Writer Thread

```
protected class Writer implements Runnable {
    String url;

    public void run() {
        FileOutputStream out_file = null;
        File cacheFile = new File("url-file");
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int count = 0;
        try {
            URL urlstream = new URL(url);
            // cv is an object which stores url information
            cv.originInputStream = urlstream.openStream();
            out_file = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
            while ((count = cv.originInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out_file.write(buf, 0, count);
                out_file.flush();
                cv.incrementTotalBytes(count);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the next request I need to read the locally saved file, url-file, and move to the last saved position in it. I am using totalBytes attribute of cv object which gives me total byte saved by the writer thread.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("url-file");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
                + localFile.getName());
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        int count = 0;
        FileChannel inc = in.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
        inc.position(cv.getTotalBytes());

        while ((count = inc.read(b)) >= 0) {
            out.write(b.array(), 0, count);
            b.clear();
        }
```

I do not see any output, what is the best way to seek in a file, which is getting updated by another thread.

EDIT: I expect the writer thread to keep on writing to the file and the response for any request should start from that instance of time. In nutshell, my writer thread is still writing to file when setting the position in the file channel. Even if I set the file channel position to 25% less say `inc.position(totalBytes - (long) 0.25 * totalBytes)` I still do not see output.

Comment: Why do you set the `inc` position to the end before reading? Subsequent reads would not return anything if the file would not be appended to in the meantime. Since you want to serve the saved file on subsequent requests, why don't you start at position 0?

Comment: So you only serve parts of the file? Like not the entire HTML document but only what was appended by the writer since the last iteration?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I want to start from that instance of time. Its like a live feed. I expect my writer thread to keep on writing to the file. Added this in question.

Comment: Yes, only part of the file, starting from when the request was made.

Comment: So you'd need to store the position the reader ended at and resume from there. Don't start at the end of the file (see Andreas' answer).

Comment: I understand it is to do with reader position, even if I do `inc.position(totalBytes - (long) 0.25 * totalBytes)` I dont see any output :(

Comment: actually `(long) 0.25 = 0` thus `(long) 0.25 * totalBytes = 0`, try `(long) (0.25 * totalBytes)`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me, that `cv` holds a the number of total bytes in the file. There's an update call to `cv` each time you append data to the file.

The second snippet seems to use the same value ("filesize") as a marker in the file channel. To my understanding, you always set the marker on the last byte in the file and try to start reading *from* that position and, obviously, you'll see EOF immediatly.

Rethink your method of calculating the starting position for the response. It shouldn't be the last byte at the file.

Comment: Hi Andreas, I expect the writer thread to keep on writing to the file and the response for any request should start from that instance of time.In nutshell, my Writer thread is still writing when I am setting the position in the file channel. I tried setting the position to 75% of total bytes saved but no output :(